# Karabiner: how to toggle Caps Lock when the Caps Lock key is already used for something else?

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

I have changed the settings on macOS so that the Caps Lock key is used to switch between English and other languages. (The "true" caps lock (with LED) is now toggled by pressing down it for a longer time.)

Now I wish to use Karabiner to map, for example, control + K to the **true** Caps Lock which toggles capitalisation.

Is that possible?

Comment: You should try to do it first before asking the question.

Comment: @IlyaRodionov Well - how could I try if I do not know the api? I have already read the docs and have not found anything.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you want to know how to remap `control+K` to `CapsLock` in Karabiner-Elements? If so, you should rephrase your question.